# Applescript saving each item from a list as text

Tags: arrays, list, applescript

I have a list of numbers (the number of numbers is random)

for example here is my current result :

```
Result:
{"1024343495", "84734348416", "100434439171", "86343425", "13434290", "83434946", "81711343497", "43534347319", "863434490"}
```

I would like to print them in a text file, or save in the clipboard, but this is not working

```
set the clipboard to myList
```

so I tried to convert the all as a string :

```
set the clipboard to myList as string
```

but then I have just a huge number :
1024343495847343484161004344391718634342513434290834349468171134349743534347319863434490

Comment: http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/applescript-script-libraries-text-utils-command-join-list-items/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
set myString to ""
set i to 0
repeat (number of items in myList) times
    set i to i + 1
    set myString to myString & ((item i of myList)as string) &  ", "-- this last bit here is what goes in between each list item
end repeat
return myString
```

result "1024343495, 84734348416, 100434439171"-etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use your code after setting `text item delimiters` accordingly.

```
set myList to {"1024343495", "84734348416", "100434439171", "86343425", "13434290", "83434946", "81711343497", "43534347319", "863434490"}
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ", "}
set the clipboard to myList as text
set text item delimiters to TID
```